# Google Places API InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, html, google-places-api

Have an HTML-form with this element:

```js
var control = container.getElementById('AutoComplete');
var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */ (control);
console.log("input: ", input); //Output: <input type=​"text" id=​"AutoComplete" placeholder=​"--" class=​"block_input" autocomplete=​"off">​
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
  types: ['geocode']
});
```

```html
<html>
<div id="input_address">
  <div class="element">
    <label class="block_label">Адрес</label>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <input type="text" id="AutoComplete" placeholder="--" class="block_input"></input>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

I have an error:

> not an instance of HTMLInputElement

How can I fix this?

Comment: Google maps autocomplete now supports only window.HTMLInputElement

Comment: `new google.maps.places.Autocomplete` is asynchronous. Isn't the input destroyed/deleted/removed after calling the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this method worked.

```
 let searchInputField = document.getElementsByClassName('search-form')[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
 let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchInputField);
```

Answer (score -1):

it can be removed from the console by just adding hidden input with the id autocomplete like this
 **`<input id="autocomplete"  type="hidden">`**